# elpy tries to make a virtual env, but fails and starts complaining, very much complaining

Tags: elpy

I have installed `elpy` tonight, but it seems that it cannot start properly a Python virtualenv, and it's complaining as reported below.

First, I installed `use-package` and `elpy` from Melpa, and I added, per `elpy`'s manual,

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :init
  (elpy-enable))
```

to my init file.

Next, I opened a Python file and I got this message

```
error in process sentinel: elpy-promise-reject: peculiar error: "exited abnormally with code 1"
error in process sentinel: peculiar error: "exited abnormally with code 1"
```

At this point I turned on debug on error, and promptly I got this backtrace

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (process-sentinel "exited abnormally with code 1")
  elpy-rpc--default-error-callback((process-sentinel "exited abnormally with code 1"))
  elpy-promise-reject([*elpy-promise* #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_30> elpy-rpc--default-error-callback #<buffer  *elpy-rpc [project:~/Documents/Code/ environment:/usr]*> nil] (process-sentinel "exited abnormally with code 1"))
  #f(compiled-function (call-id promise) #<bytecode 0x15ab78ddb8c11359>)(1 [*elpy-promise* #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_30> elpy-rpc--default-error-callback #<buffer  *elpy-rpc [project:~/Documents/Code/ environment:/usr]*> nil])
  elpy-rpc--sentinel(#<process  *elpy-rpc [project:~/Documents/Code/ environment:/usr]*> "exited abnormally with code 1\n")
```

How can I solve this issue?

---

Followup to [Drew's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) comment (TL;DR it's not an interference from other packages).

1. I started Emacs with `emacs -Q`
2. I evaluated

   ```
    (require 'package)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
    (package-initialize)

    ;; If there are no archived package contents, refresh them
    (when (not package-archive-contents)
      (package-refresh-contents))
    (use-package elpy
      :ensure t
      :init
      (elpy-enable))
   ```
3. I opened a Pyton source code file, and I've experienced the same behaviour described above.

Comment: Find out what program elpy was running (probably `elpy-rpc-python-command`), and find out what it means when it exits with error code 1. Then you’ll know what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If so, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If not, report a bug to the Elpy maintainer.

Comment: @Drew TY for the suggestion, I did what you've asked (details in the edited answer) but the problem remains.

Comment: Unless you get a helpful answer here (or at help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org), I'd suggest contacting the Elpy maintainer.